# making links with out anchor tag using dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, hyperlink

I have a image with link
 `<div id="img"><a href="src/blah.html"><img src="/src/img.png"/></a></div>`
 but i don't wanna use  tag for linking.the page has multiple entries like this in a page as it is being populated for a search result.Some 10 or more entries will be there in a page.its all inside a `<div id="result"></div>`

have an idea for doing it dojo.help me finish that

`function(){
     dojo.query('.Result').forEach(function(item){
     try{
     var href = dojo.query('.img',item)[0]
     //do things
     dojo.connect(Node,'onclick',dojo.hitch(this,function(){
      window.location = location;
     }));`

Comment: Are you attempting to remove the anchor tags and replace the functionality with an `onclick` event? If so, where is the source of the `href` or the location? If the `a` tags don't exist, you can't do the linking unless you store the URL / locations somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
<div id="result">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img location="src/blah.html" src="/src/img.png"></div>
</div>

dojo.query("#result .imageContainer img").connect("onclick", function() {
    var location = dojo.attr(this, "location");
    if (location) {
        window.location.href = location;
    }
});
```